# Finding a cost function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Can you find a cost function $C$ which takes vectors of $\mathrm{R}^d$ such that $\forall a,b,c \in \mathrm{R}^d,$ if $C(b) \leq C(c),$ then $C(a+b) \geq C(a+c)$.

This function would verify all the properties of a cost function (non-negativity, null in zero, monoticity, continuity, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b, c \in  \mathbb R^n$ such that $C(b) \leq C(c)$.

\begin{align*}
C(b) &\le C(c) \tag{assumption}\\
C(0+b) &\ge C(0+c)\tag{property: $C(a+b) \ge C(a+c)$} \\
C(b) &\ge C(c) \tag{Simplify above}\\
C(b) &= C(c) \tag{$[C(b) \le C(c)] \land [C(b) \ge C(c)] $}
\end{align*}

That is, there are no non-trivial solutions to this cost.

In the 1-D analysis, the cost function $f(x) = -x$ as proposed above does not satisfy the constraints. Since if we have that $C(b) \leq C(b)$, then we have that $-b \leq -c \implies b \ge c$. However, $C(a+b) = -(a+b) = -a -b$ is *not* greater that $C(a+c) = -a -c$:
$$-b \le -c
\implies -a-b \le -b-c
$$

The issue was the confusion between $C(b) \leq C(c)$ and $b \leq c$.